# Пытаюсь сохранить в базу время и получаю ошибку Не удалось преобразовать значение PHP типа строка. Ожидается один из следующих типов: null, DateTime

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь сохранить текущее время в таблицу формата DateTime. Но не получается

Попытки сохранения :

```
$dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Моя Entity :

```
/**
 * @var DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="status_time", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $statusTime;
```

Полная ошибка :
Could not convert PHP value '2022-06-06 10:40:17' of type 'string' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так переменную инициализировать и записать в базу

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
```

Comment: Это сработало. Спасибо!